# Add clear button in Date Picker for Oracle Apex

Tags: jquery, oracle, oracle-apex, apex

Is it possible to add clear button in date picker? I have this item that is read only to avoid wrong format when inputting. So, I'm thinking of a solution to add clear button inside the date picker in Oracle APEX. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add a Quick pick to the Item.

1. Go to the Item attributes and switch on the **Show Quick Picks** option and enter the value of the **Label1** as Clear and leave the **Value1** field empty.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But is it possible to put quick pick inside the date picker?

Comment: Not inside the date picker. It will display below the date picker item